# Angular DropDown - Unable to display value on View

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu

In my component I have 2 Strings that I need to display on Angular Form as Dropdown, I am struggling to get the values on HTML page

Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dc4s7d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Here is my ts code

```
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public employeeService: EmployeeService) {}
  public listItem: string[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.listItem = ["A", "B"];  ----->>>>> Dropdown values
  }
```

Html code

```
 <div class="m-3 input-group; padding:10px; color:red; border: 3px solid ">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">Type</span>
                                    <select type="text" name="type" #type="ngModel"
                                        [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.type "placeholder="Type">
                                        <option *ngFor="let dl of listItem" [value]="dl">{{dl}}</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Hey, Please check my new update. It should work. Please check and try it and let me know. Best wishes. :)

Comment: There is not property called `employeeService.selectedEmployee` is available in `app.component.ts` TS File. That is the main error and check the console. You will find the errors . If you resolve those errors your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Something may be wrong with your code but I can provide you a sample code to bind data with dropdown list. Please check and let me know.
**HTML**

```
<select name="city" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries"  [value]="country.id">{{country.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**TS:**

```
 countries = [{
    id: 1, name: 'France', cities: ['Paris', 'Marseille', 'Nice']
  },
  {
    id: 2, name: 'Germany', cities: ['Hamburg', 'Berlin', 'Munich']
  },
  {
    id: 3, name: 'Italy', cities: ['Roma', 'Milan', 'Napoli']
  },
  ];
 
onChange(deviceValue) {
    //do something
  }
```

**Note:** Please Check the link of Stackblitz for more information [LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

**NEW UPDATE**
I think `employeeService.selectedEmployee` is not available on that link. That's the reason why your code was not working and You have to make a little change in `listitem`. 
Finally, code will look like =>

**TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  selectedtype: any;
   listItems= [{ name: 'A'},{ name: 'B'}];
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onChange(deviceValue) {
    
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name="dt" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedtype" placeholder="Type"
        #type="ngModel" type="text">
  <option *ngFor="let data of listItems"  [value]="data.name">{{data.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

**NOTE:** Provide link contain 4 errors.

Comment: I tried this example, did not work for me

Comment: I have added stackbiltz in my question

Comment: It still did not work- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tj3oga?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: There is not property called `employeeService.selectedEmployee` is available in `app.component.ts` TS File. That is the main error and check the console. You will find the errors . If you resolve those errors your code will work.

Comment: This is Employee class `export class Employee {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  designation: string;
  salary: number;
  date: Date;
  type: string[];
}
`   In my service I initialized `selectedEmployee: Employee;`    Its just that code is large so I just add things necessary in codeblitz
`  I do not see any errors in console

Comment: Please add all relevant classes and objects in that stackblitz link .then let me know. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227871/discussion-between-linker-and-paritosh-m).

Answer (score 0):

Try Using :

You need to initialize your **selectedEmployee** in you service file

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class EmployeeService {
  public selectedEmployee: Employee = {
    _id: '',
    name: '',
    date: null,
    designation: '',
    salary: null,
    type: null
  };
  constructor() {}
}
```

Check in your **stackblitz** demo path.

I think this will help you...